# Is JQuery $.post() asynchronous?

Tags: jquery

Is $.post asynchronous?  So if I did the commands like so below would they all be done at once instead of being synchronous (1 done, wait, then the next, etc.) ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var variable1 = '1';
    var variable2 = '2';
    var variable3 = '3';
    var variable4 = '4';

    $.post("process.php", {element1: variable1}, function(data){
        $("#area1").html(data);
    });

    $.post("process.php", {element2: variable2}, function(data){
        $("#area3").html(data);
    });

    $.post("process.php", {element3: variable3}, function(data){
        $("#area4").html(data);
    });

    $.post("process.php", {element4: variable4}, function(data){
        $("#area4").html(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, AJAX requests are asynchronous.  You can test this by executing the code you've shown.

Comment: ajax calls are asynchronous and that would mean $.post is asynchronous

Comment: I don't get the down votes for a good question.  It was hard to find this information out.  Most websites are vague on this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All ajax request are asynchronos as it acronym suggest.
(Asynchronous Javascript and XML)

You can refer the api documentation of $.post() in [Jquery website](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Which clearly says that

> This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> $.ajax({
>   type: "POST",
>   url: url,
>   data: data,
>   success: success,
>   dataType: dataType
> });
> ```
>
> The success callback function is passed the returned data, which will
>   be an XML root element or a text string depending on the MIME type of
>   the response. It is also passed the text status of the response.

From above extract we can understand that $.post() is asynchronous.

For jquery versions < 1.8 you can use `async:false` to make it synchronous.
Afterwards it is depreciated.
Anyway it is not a recommended practice to use this parameter

For jquery versions >= 1.8 you can use `.done()` callback. in which you can add all your operations which you need to perform after ajax call

Comment: Found out there is a glitch in $.post, and this is now my preferred way to do this! YAY

Answer (score 17):

By default `$.post()` function is asynchronous

If you want it to be synchronous Samuel J Mathew's is correct. 
But if you want to keep using `$.post()` instead of `$.ajax()`, you should do it this way:

```
$.ajaxSetup({async: false});  
$.post();
```

remember to set async back to true. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant solution to what you want to do would be to store all the data in a single JSON and send it over to your php and then answer with another JSON and decode the data so you can update all in a single call. I'd code it but i don't know how your php or html works.